# system verilog bind used together with interface

Tags: system-verilog

I defined an interface in system verilog and use bind statement to bind to internal RTL signals. I want to be able to force internal RTL signals through the interface. However, this is causing the RTL signal to go to 'x' if I don't force these signals explicitly, it seems bind to interface is having driving capability. I don't want RTL signal to change to 'x' when nothing is forcing it in this case, not sure what I am doing wrong here?

my code looks like this with DUT being the design:

```
interface myInf(
   inout RTL_a,
   inout RTL_b 
);

bind DUT myInf myInf_inst(
   .RTL_a(DUT.a),
   .RTL_b(DUT.b)
);

bind DUT myDrv(myInf_inst);
```

where myDrv is a module which drives the ports on myInf.

In this case, DUT.a and DUT.b are internal RTL signals, they have their driver from design, but I want to be able to force them if needed. however, these signals becoming 'x' when I am just binding them to myInf without actually driving them.

Comment: It seems your RTL signals will have multiple drivers in this case, please correct me if I'm wrong but multiple drivers won't resolve to stable value if all drivers don't have same values. Furthermore default values of signals (unless they are declared new systemverilog type) is 'X'. Oh another thing you will need to 'release' signals which are forced.

Answer (score 3):

The `inout` signals might be a non-net type. It is better to be explicit in the the declaration and define them as `inout wire`. Inside the `interface`, assign the nets to a `logic` and initialize the `logic`s to `z`. A non-`z` value will apply a driver while a `z` will allow signals to drive. Example:

```
interface myInf(
   inout wire RTL_a,
   inout wire RTL_b 
);
  logic drv_a, drv_b;
  initial {drv_a,drv_b} = 'z; // z means not driving
  assign RTL_a = drv_a;
  assign RTL_b = drv_b;
endinterface
```

There might be conflicting drivers, such as the normal drivers from the design. In this case you will need to override the driver. Assuming the signal being overrode is a net type, this is done by changing the assign statements to `assign (supply1,suppl0) RTL_a = drv_a;`. This is utilizing the Verilog concept of drive strength. Assigning to `z` will still all other drivers. Most nets are driven with a strength of `strong1,strong0` which is weaker then `supply1,supply0`. Drive strength will not work for non-net types (e.g. `logic` & `reg`). These register/variable-types use a last-assignment-wins approach. Fore more on drive strength read [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) sections 28.11 through 28.15

---

Your sample code has some bugs.  The pin connections for `myInf_inst` should use hierarchical references relative to its target scope. Unless there is an instance called `DUT` inside `module DUT`, then the `DUT.` should be omitted (See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 23.11 *Binding auxiliary code to scopes or instances*). The bind statement for `myDrv` is missing an instance name. The code should be:

```
bind DUT myInf myInf_inst(
   .RTL_a(a), // no DUT.
   .RTL_b(b) // no DUT.
);

bind DUT myDrv myDrv_inst(myInf_inst);
```

sample code: http://www.edaplayground.com/x/2NG